# Adobe Air - use a flash swf to tunnel to a proxy?

Tags: flash, proxy, air, adobe

I want to create an Air app (HTML and JS) that has the ability to use user entered proxy settings. While I know that by default Air will use the OS's proxy settings, I was wondering it if was possible to include a small swf that got it's settings from Air, and then created a "tunnel" to a proxy to pass the request on to.

Are there examples of a swf that will do this anywhere? Is this possible with the Air sandboxing?